# Escape quote in python os.system("command")

Tags: python, escaping, os.system

I want to run the following command via os.system(`command`)

```
echo '@include("acf/rows.php")' >>  ../functions.php
```

I can't seem to get the escaping of quotes right. How do I do this?

Comment: `os.system('echo \'@include(\"acf/rows.php\")\' >>  ../functions.php')`?

Comment: Where is your `os.system()` attempt?

Comment: Please provide us with your code so that we can reproduce your error.

Comment: @Tomothy32: OP wants to do it with python using `os`

Comment: Why not append to the file using Python file functions instead of this double indirect method…?!

Comment: @Bazingaa I meant to put that string into into `os.system`. See my edit.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Thank you! This works perfectly!

Comment: @deceze even better! Changed my code to append it, very new to Python. Thanks so much :)

Comment: The question is tagged as Python, so I assume you are calling this from Python. That implies putting the whole string into another pair of quotes. Show your Python code, so that we can see what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
os.system('echo \'@include(\"acf/rows.php\")\' >> ../functions.php')
```

Works great thanks to @Tomothy32

Even better:

```
with open("../functions.php", "a") as functions:
        functions.write("@import('acf/rows.php');")
```

Thanks to @deceze